# @media screen not being read

Tags: css, media-queries

Why won't this work to hide my header element between 421px and 640px widths?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 421px) and (max-width: 640px) {

    #slidehead { display: none; }


}
```

Comment: Some browsers don't support media queries as much as we'd want them to.

Comment: So, it didn't work as apart of an external stylesheet. But when I put this in the head of my document it worked just fine. Odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to be called inline within my header before taking effect; works now - but odd.